# Trigger plotAreaClick event while using plot bands in KendoUI charts

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui, event-handling, kendo-chart

I have several column charts in one page.  I utilize the `seriesClick` and `plotAreaClick` events within those charts to trigger some filtering.  Charts where I don't use plot bands have no issues triggering the `plotAreaClick`.  As soon as I introduce a plot band to a chart - the `plotAreaClick` event stops triggering.

Anyone know of a workaround?  Am I the only one to experience this?

Comment: can you maybe show some code? that usually works much better to get help fro coders, then a vague textual explanation of your code.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UCoBIg